# Portacle Common Lisp connection to Swank Hangs

Tags: common-lisp

I have a Portacle installation on Windows 10. Sometimes it works properly, sometimes it doesn't. The problem occurs when Portacle is started and it attempts to connect to Swank. Emacs freezes, and I cannot edit anything in the editing windows (therefore, sorry, I cannot copy the messages to show you). The Emacs editor looks like this:

[image]

That's it. If I make Emacs full screen, the editor window is blank.

Thoughts, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once wrote this article - and there I explain also how to install Roswell and with the help of Roswell a Common Lisp implementation and connect with emacs/slime. Roswell is definitely to be preferred over Portacle.

If you install first `scoop`, installing Roswell becomes trivial. (`scoop install roswell`).
https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-set-up-common-lisp-ide-in-2021-5be70d88975b
Once, Roswell is installed, you install `sbcl` easily by `ros install sbcl`. You can install then several versions of sbcl - but especially all the other Common Lisp implementations, too. And switch between them by `ros use` command. How to install emacs and slime is explained there, too.

Portacle is bound to sbcl and cannot jump between versions and implementations. Plus Roswell is not buggy like Portacle is.